# ReplaceFirst with Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Let's say I have a String

```
String link = "www.thisisalink.com/tick1=@tick1@&tick2=@tick2@&tick3=@tick3@&tick4=@tick4@";
```

Then I can use

```
link = replaceFirst("(.+)=@\\1@", "");
```

To make it

```
link = "www.thisisalink.com/&tick2=@tick2@&tick3=@tick3@&tick4=@tick4@";
```

But I want to loop though the String, to get what has been replace and save it somewhere else, like a linked list or an array... result would be:

```
String[] result = ["tick1=@tick1@", "tick2=@tick2@", "tick3=@tick3@", "tick4=@tick4@"];
String link = "www.thisisalink.com/&&&";
```

But how can I do this? I tried looping with

```
while (link.matches("(.+)=@\\1@")){}
```

Which didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Pattern` `Matcher` classes to iterate over your string to find substrings that will match your regex. Then to replace founded substring you can use `appednReplacement` and `appendTail`. To get founded match you can use `group()` from Matcher instance.

Here is something similar to what you want

```
String link = "www.thisisalink.com/tick1=@tick1@&tick2=@tick2@&tick3=@tick3@&tick4=@tick4@";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+)=@\\1@");
Matcher m = p.matcher(link);
List<String> replaced = new ArrayList<>();

while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
    replaced.add(m.group());
}
m.appendTail(sb);
//to replace link with String stored in sb use link=sb.toString();
//otherwise link will be unchanged
System.out.println(sb);
System.out.println(replaced);
```

output:

```
www.thisisalink.com/&&&
[tick1=@tick1@, tick2=@tick2@, tick3=@tick3@, tick4=@tick4@]
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the Strings you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String link = "www.thisisalink.com/tick1=@tick1@&tick2=@tick2@&tick3=@tick3@&tick4=@tick4@";
    final int index = link.indexOf("/") + 1;

    final String[] result = link.substring(index).split("&");
    final String newLink = link.substring(0, index) + repeat("&", result.length -1);
    System.out.println(newLink);
    for(final String tick : result)
    {
        System.out.println(tick);
    }
}

private static String repeat(final String toRepeat, final int repetitions)
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(repetitions);
    for(int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
    {
        sb.append(toRepeat);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Produces:

```
www.thisisalink.com/&&&
tick1=@tick1@
tick2=@tick2@
tick3=@tick3@
tick4=@tick4@
```

Comment: Thank you, but i like the other solution more... thanks for your effort though.